# Change a specified column to DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn in DotNetBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

This question requires you to be familiar with [DotNetBar UI](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) library for Windows Forms.

I know how to add a `DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn` to a `DataGridViewX`, but it's useful only when I know which columns the DataGridViewX has. The problem is I don't know which columns the `DataGridViewX` has, it's DataSource can change and the columns will be automatically populated. The only thing I know is the type of column (specified by the column name or column data type) I want to turn it into a `DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn`.

I don't know if I can do this in DotNetBar, if not, it's a real pity, in DevExpress I can do this but the work is also not simple.

Comment: Looks like DotNetBar is a paid component suite. So why don't you ask their support?

Comment: It's so sad for their support, I've tried visiting DotNetBar forum and it's so sad, the number of threads is only 400, it's not busy as in DevExpress forum. I've used DevExpress before, but I want to try DotNetBar this time for my project. Thanks!

Comment: I've never been to Devexpress forums, but their regular/ticket support is working very well, if you know what you want. Even while in trial mode (first 30 days). Are you saying that DotNetBar don't have an official trial support?

Comment: No, I just searched for its forum and I see It can't help, the support there is not good, I don't think is has so small number of threads, about a private support request, I think it is worth trying. Thanks for your suggestion. By the way, I've found another control which may help, it's SuperGridControl in DotNetBar. Thanks!